# Get Number of character array C++

Tags: c++

```
char array[] {};
cin>>array;
```

If I Run this Code the program ask user for input message so if user input "Play"

```
array[0] = P
array[1] = l
array[2] = a
array[0] = y
```

i want to make int variable which in have the number of the character that user put in 
or
the largest index of array

Thank You

Comment: `char array[] {}` is not standard c++. It uses a gcc extension. Rather use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a fixed capacity, either at compile time:

```
char text[1024];
```

or dynamically allocated during runtime:

```
cout << "Enter text length: ";
size_t length;
cin >> length;
char *text2 = new char[length];
```

For text, there is the `std::string` type which will expand as necessary:

```
std::string word;
cout << "Enter word: ";
cin >> word;
cout << "Length of word: " << word.length() << "\n";
```

If you *must* use character arrays, you need to use the `str*()` family of functions:

```
char hello[]="hello";
cout << "Length is: " << strlen(hello) << "\n";
```

The preferred method is to use `std::string` for text and `std::vector` for arrays.

*Warning:  don't use `cin >> character_array`, as `cin` doesn't know the size of the array and you could overflow.*
Example:

```
char word[2];
cin >> word;
```

*Now, type in "world", and the array would be overflowed.*